# Root Amazon Echo and install linux kernel - what programs can run on it?

Tags: linux, echo, iot

I have an old v1 Echo that I want to experiment with. Using this guide, I see it's possible to root this Echo and install a custom linux kernel (2.6.x) on it: https://github.com/echohacking/wiki/wiki/Echo

My question is: should this in theory allow anything that could run on that version of linux to run on the Echo (withing the limits of memory/processor etc)? Specifically I'd like to have the Echo automatically play sound files after it boots (without using it as a bluetooth speaker etc), which would be v simple to run on a basic linux system - is this feasible?

Comment: It depends entirely on what facilities the new system you install on it has. This question would only be on topic here as far as running standard Linux commands on it, general questions regarding random media player devices are off topic here.